# How to set a font to a TextField

Tags: itext

I would like to set a font to a TextField I add using the PdfStamper class. My code is as follows:

```
final TextField textField = new TextField(
        stamper.getWriter(), 
        new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury), 
        "Name"
);
textField.setOptions(TextField.READ_ONLY);
textField.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

final BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
    "c:/windows/fonts/comic.ttf",
    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 
    BaseFont.EMBEDDED
); 
bf.setSubset(false);

textField.setFont(bf);
textField.setFontSize(12);
textField.setText("Žížalka");

stamper.addAnnotation(textField.getTextField(), 1);
```

I set bf.setSubset to false because I would like to be able to change the field value later with javascript.

Well, the PDF file is generated and the field contains the word with Comic Sans MS font as expected, but when I click to the field it changes to a group of weird characters, although it is still Comic Sans MS font. What is wrong here? The font is embedded to the file so why it draws the word wrong?

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF to illustrate the issue. Furthermore, in which program do you *click to the field* to witness that *it changes to a group of weird characters*? Adobe Reader? Which version?

Comment: How can provide the PDF file? I don't see any 'attach file' option here. It is Adobe Reader 11.0.3.

Comment: StackOverflow does not provide a generic file upload mechanism. Usually such files are provided by some other file sharing medium (preferably one without ads or need to sign in), e.g. via DropBox or Google, and a link is included in the question or in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem. I had to change `comis.ttf` to `comic.ttf`. I was able to create a correct looking PDF without any problem. See [hello_field.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/hello_field.pdf).

However, there's something I don't like in your code (it's known to have caused many problems for other people): you're putting non-ASCII characters in your source file: `"Žížalka"`

That is *not done*. These characters will get corrupted if you save your source file using the wrong encoding. These characters will get corrupted if you compile your source file using the wrong encoding. Etc.

My guess is that your problem is an encoding problem. You should replace the non-ASCII characters with their UNICODE notations like this:

Don't use:

```
textField.setText("Žížalka");
```

Use:

```
textField.setText("\u017d\u00ed\u017ealka");
```

This will avoid all kinds of encoding-related problems.

**DISCLAIMER:** if it's not an encoding problem, something else may be at play. I'm only giving you the most likely cause of the problem. It may also be something else, such as a bug in an older version of iText.

Comment: Thanks for correcting - it was "comic" in my code too. I don't know where I get "comis". Well, it looks like it's the Acrobat reader problem, because the PDF you provided is broken too on my PC. Whether I click in 'Hello World' or 'Žížalka', the value of the field with 'Žížalka' changes to some funny characters. I have tried to send it to my colleague and he reports the same behavior. We both have Windows 7 (czech localization), I have localized Acrobat reader, my colleague has the English version.

Comment: By the way it doesn't matter if it's 'Žížalka' or 'Zizalka', the field value is broken as well.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought the characters weren't displayed correctly when opening the document. I overlooked the fact that the characters were wrong when you click them. Now I also see that behavior.

Comment: I've changed the font to `comicbd.ttf` and now the problem seems to have disappeared. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: Yes, but only partially. When I click to it first time, it gets little smaller but it's ok. Then I click somewhere else and again in the filed. Then it gets wrong as before. You can try e.g. the 'Verdana' font, it has the same problem.

Comment: The problem can also be fixed by removing the line `bf.setSubset(false);`

Comment: What helps is not to use bf.setSubset(false). Then when I click to the field, the content is the same 'Žížalka' although in different font. Weird. But I need to call bf.setSubset(false) anyway because I need to embed the whole font in the PDF.

Comment: Why do you need the complete font?

Comment: The field value is changed when opening the document using some javascript code. Every page contains exactly one such a field and it's filled by a dynamically computed text.

Comment: You get better results when using `BaseFont.CP1250` instead of `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`. However, for some reason the Z-caron changes into the TM symbol.

Comment: And the problem is completely solved when using `BaseFont.WINANSI`.

Comment: Interesting. Can I change existing BaseFont encoding?

Comment: I don't understand the additional question.

Comment: When i get a BaseFont (I don't create it), can I change its encoding?

Comment: No, the `createFont()` method does plenty of stuff that requires the encoding to be known at the moment of creation.

Comment: Ok, I have a last additional question. When I use the WINANSI encoding and set 'řehole' instead of 'Žížalka' the field value is rendered wrong when opening the document - as expected, because WINANSI(CP1252) doesn't contain 'ř', but it gets right after I click in the field. Do you have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: That's funny indeed. In Bruno's original sample the field **/V** value is correctly **PdfDocEncoding** encoded; thus, Acrobat Reader should know what to display. Even the **ToUnicode** map correctly maps the CIDs back to the right Unicode characters; thus, even if the Reader was using the data from the appearance stream instead of the field value, it should know. Thus, it essentially seems to be in trouble using the Adobe-Identity-0 Identity-H composite embedded font to create an own appearance stream for the field value.

Comment: To mkl: we've discussed for hours about fonts at the Adobe offices in Seattle ( http://lowagie.com/node/490 ) last week: fonts aren't easy. To Behnil: when you open the file, you see an appearance created by iText; when you click a field, you see an appearance created by Adobe Reader. You could try using a substitution font to make sure iText creates the correct appearance, and then count on Adobe Reader to render the field correctly.

Comment: Ok, but both (iText and Reader) use the same embedded font (Comic Sans MS, CP1252). So why the appearance created by iText is wrong (as expected because CP1252 doesn't contain 'ř') and Reader appearance contains 'ř'. Does Acrobat change encoding internally somehow?

Comment: My guess: iText accesses the font using CP1252 and if no substitution font is defined, it doesn't know how to draw the glyph. Acrobat sees a special character without a glyph and looks in other fonts using other encodings to find that glyph. Note that you may be confused because you have the /V on one hand, and the /AP appearance on the other hand. If you only look at the outside of the document, you could easily forget that these are two different things.